# How to draw the graph of a $2 \pi$ periodic function defined as $f(x)=1 \forall x \in (0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

This might seem as a dumb question, but I am really unsure how to do it. I am asked to draw the graph of a $2 \pi$ periodic function such that $$f(x)=1 \forall x \in (0,1), \: and \: \: f(0)=f(\pi)=0$$

Now it's obvious for me how to draw it on the interval $(0,1)$, but I am unsure how to do it on $(1,2 \pi)$. After all no indication is given about the $[0, 2\pi] \backslash (0,1)$ interval. How should I proceed?

Comment: Proceed any way you want. It doesn't matter, just as long as $f(2\pi) = 0$.It's not going to be continuous, but that can't be helped. Then force the graph to repeat (forwards and backwards). The simplest solution (from a graphical point of view is to make the function $0$ except on $(0,1)$.

Comment: When no further indication is given, you can think of it as just doing one example. Yes, there are many more examples to be drawn, but you are not asked to draw all of them; just draw one of them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You need to define $f$ on one period $[a,a+2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example

[image]

In the region $(1, 2\pi)$ you have a lot of freedom, the only constraint is $f(\pi) = 0$

**NOTE** There title says $f(0) = f(\pi) = \color{orange}{\bf 1}$, the body says $f(0) = f(\pi) = \color{orange}{\bf 0}$, I picked the last one for the sketch